What is happening with the formatting of this question?
How to point subdomain to AWS Amplify?
The original question is not displaying properly.  Some of the content in my answer is a grey square.

And when I try to edit I see this.  Never seen this before on SO.


What browser and operating system are you using?  The answer appears normally for me both on the page and when editing for me on Firefox Linux.

I thought that the gray boxes that you circled in red might be some weird Unicode character, but it looks like that is just normal backtick code formatting markdown.

Latest firefox on Win 11

When I went to post this answer, I couldn't type in the text box.
It looks like it was a browser issue of some sort.  Closing and restarting the browser seems to have fixed it all.
